# How to save downloaded files in a private directory in a Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, dart

`final Directory tempDir = Directory.systemTemp;`

If I store my downloaded file in tempDir, Can it be shareable or accessible with other devices?
That means, can data leak possibly occur?

I want to save the downloaded file on my device but not sharable or accessible with any device. How can I achieve it using the Flutter application?

Answer (score 0):

> You can try below example:

> add path provider and permission_handler dependencies

```
 String? path;
  Future<String?> _getDir() async {
    try {
      var status = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (!status.isGranted) {
        await Permission.storage.request();
      }

      Directory? appDirectory;
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        appDirectory = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Music");
      } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
        appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      }
      path = '${appDirectory!.path}/recording.wav';
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }

    setState(() {});
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: If I save my file using your approach, Is it possible to leak my data which means can data be sharable or accessible with other devices?

Comment: as per my code  you can save data in internal storage on physical device